# Where are Windows 10 privacy settings stored in the registry?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

Where are privacy settings stored in the registry? Windows 10 resets them after every update for me... I would like to make a registry file that turns them to my preferences.

Comment: Are you talking about the monthly security updates or the feature upgrades release twice a year? If it is the latter please consider that Microsoft can change the registry paths of those settings by such updates (which is a possible reason why you loose the privacy settings).

Comment: See this>>>>>https://www.joseespitia.com/2017/03/06/registry-keys-for-windows-10-privacy-settings/

Comment: @Moab: Unfortunately, the registry keys from the article which I tried don't exist on my Windows 10.

Comment: You should include everything you tried in your question, that way we don't waste time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the article
[Registry Keys for Windows 10 Application Privacy Settings](https://www.joseespitia.com/2019/07/24/registry-keys-for-windows-10-application-privacy-settings/),
the registry keys below each contains a REG_SZ item named `Value` that is either
`Allow` or `Deny`.

**Location:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\location

**Webcam:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\webcam

**Microphone:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\microphone

**Notifications:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\userNotificationListener

**Motion:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\activity

**Account Info:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\userAccountInformation

**Contacts:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\contacts

**Calendar:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\appointments

**Call History:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\phoneCallHistory

**Email:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\email

**Tasks:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\userDataTasks

**Messaging:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\chat

**Radios:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\radios

**Other Devices:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\bluetoothSync

**Background Apps:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search

**App Diagnostics:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\appDiagnostics

**Documents:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\documentsLibrary

**Pictures:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\picturesLibrary

**Videos:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\videosLibrary

**File Systems:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\broadFileSystemAccess

The article
[Windows 10 privacy settings](https://4sysops.com/wiki/windows-10-privacy-settings)
adds these settings:

**Sync info with wireless devices:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DeviceAccess\Global\LooselyCoupled

**Improve typing:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Input\TIPC

Value name: Enabled
Value data: 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

Based on a script by Chris Wellons, below is a cmd batch script `lessmal.bat` I put together (the latest version at https://gitlab.com/0mid/dotfiles/-/blob/master/lessmal.bat), which automates disabling a few of the numerous malicious features (and some nuisances) of Windows.

*The aim of this script is NOT to promote/encourage the use of the proprietary (non-free) Windows operating system, which does not respect the users' freedoms (https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html). The hope is that this script makes Windows negligibly less malicious for those who cannot immediately move to a free/libre operating system (such as a GNU/Linux distribution) and are forced to use Windows.
Malicious features are objective; "misfeatures" (e.g., `TaskbarAnimations`) could be subjective, so feel free to pick and choose which one of the "misfeatures" you'd like disabled.*

`lessmal.bat` as of now; run in a cmd console (**no Admin needed**):

```
rem A one-shot, first-time Windows configuration script that disables some
rem Windows mal/misfeatures [based on Chris Wellons'].

setlocal

set key=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
reg add "%key%" /f /v AltTabSettings              /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%" /f /v DisableSearchBoxSuggestions /t REG_DWORD /d 1
set key=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
reg add "%key%" /f /v TaskbarGlomLevel          /t REG_DWORD /d 2
reg add "%key%" /f /v HideFileExt               /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%" /f /v ShowCortanaButton         /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%" /f /v ShowTaskViewButton        /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%" /f /v StoreAppsOnTaskbar        /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%" /f /v MultiTaskingAltTabFilter  /t REG_DWORD /d 3
reg add "%key%" /f /v JointResize               /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%" /f /v SnapFill                  /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%" /f /v SnapAssist                /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%" /f /v TaskbarAnimations         /t REG_DWORD /d 0
set key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Feeds
reg add "%key%" /f /v ShellFeedsTaskbarViewMode /t REG_DWORD /d 2
set key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search
reg add "%key%" /f /v SearchboxTaskbarMode      /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%" /f /v BingSearchEnabled         /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%" /f /v AllowSearchToUseLocation  /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%" /f /v CortanaConsent            /t REG_DWORD /d 0
set key=HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop
reg add "%key%" /f /v CursorBlinkRate           /t REG_SZ    /d -1
reg add "%key%" /f /v MenuShowDelay             /t REG_SZ    /d 0
reg add "%key%" /f /v UserPreferencesMask       /t REG_BINARY /d 9012078010000000
set key=HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
reg add "%key%" /f /v MinAnimate                /t REG_SZ    /d 0
set key=HKCU\Control Panel\Accessibility
reg add "%key%" /f /v DynamicScrollbars         /t REG_DWORD /d 0
set key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband
reg delete "%key%" /f /v Favorites
set key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore
reg add "%key%"\location                 /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\webcam                   /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\microphone               /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\userNotificationListener /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\activity                 /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\userAccountInformation   /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\contacts                 /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\appointments             /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\phoneCallHistory         /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\email                    /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\userDataTasks            /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\chat                     /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\radios                   /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\bluetoothSync            /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\appDiagnostics           /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\documentsLibrary         /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\picturesLibrary          /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\videosLibrary            /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
reg add "%key%"\broadFileSystemAccess    /f /v Value /t REG_SZ /d 0
set "key=HKCU\Control Panel\International\User Profile"
reg add "%key%"                          /f /v HttpAcceptLanguageOptOut /t REG_DWORD /d 1
set "key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AdvertisingInfo"
reg delete "%key%"                       /f /va
reg add "%key%"                          /f /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0
set "key=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\International"
set "val=AcceptLanguage"
reg query "%key%" /v "%val%" 2>nul && (
reg delete "%key%"                       /f /v "%val%"
)

rem Reload
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

And here is `lessmal-more.bat`, which needs to be run an **Admin cmd**, to disable a few more malicious features:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Hack to check if run by Admin [https://stackoverflow.com/a/16285248].
net session >nul 2>&1 || (echo This script requires Admin.&goto :eof)

rem Yes, this 'HKCU' key needs Admin!
set "key=HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection"
reg delete "%key%"                       /f /va

set "key=HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection"
reg add "%key%"\AllowDesktopAnalyticsProcessing             /f /v Value /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%"\LimitEnhancedDiagnosticDataWindowsAnalytics /f /v Value /t REG_DWORD /d 1
reg add "%key%"\AllowTelemetry                              /f /v Value /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%"\AllowDeviceNameInTelemetry                  /f /v Value /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%"\DisableTelemetryOptInChangeNotification     /f /v Value /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%"\AllowWUfBCloudProcessing                    /f /v Value /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%"\AllowUpdateComplianceProcessing             /f /v Value /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "%key%"\DisableTelemetryOptInSettingsUx             /f /v Value /t REG_DWORD /d 0

set "key=HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization"
reg add "%key%"\NoChangingLockScreen                        /f /v Value /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```